# left aligning a footnote in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to left align a footnote and keep the title in the center itself in my SAS output window. I tried the following code

```
proc print data = SASHELP.CLASS;
option pagesize=40 linesize=100 nodate nonumber center;
title1 "Listing 16.2.1";
title2 "Vital Sign Report of Class A";
title3 "(Confidential)";
footnote1  JUSTIFY=LEFT "M: Male, F: Female";
footnote2 " ";
run;
```

and doesn't work. Can someone be kind to enough figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justify statements (and most other formatting statements) do not work in `LISTING` (the output window).  See [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214615.htm) for more details.  They are supported in HTML, RTF, and Printer/PDF destinations, as well as other similar destinations based on these.

I would guess this originates from how they brought the style changes into SAS in the first place, documented [in this SUGI paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p002-26.pdf) from SAS 8.1.  They were added from the SAS/GRAPH options, and as such likely were added in through some of the specific drivers that produce these destinations (originally HTML, then in 8.2 RTF and Printer (which PDF is a sub-destination of).  For whatever reason they were not added in LISTING.